# Django 1.5 saving form issue, value always null

Tags: django, forms

i'm having some trouble with forms in django 1.5.
i'm trying to write a form that saves new comments on my database.
But it doesn't matter what i write in the comment textspace, it's always considered null

this is my model

```
class Comment(BaseModel):
    auction_event = models.ForeignKey(AuctionEvent, related_name='comments')
    commenter = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='comments')
    comment = models.CharField(max_length=200, default='commento', null=True, blank=True) 

    def __unicode__(self):
          return u'Placed on %s by %s' % (self.auction_event.item.title, self.commenter.username)
```

this is the form

```
class CommentForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Comment
        fields = ['comment']

      def __init__(self, data=None, auction_event=None, commenter=None, *args, **kwargs):
          self.auction_event = auction_event
          self.commenter = commenter
          super(CommentForm, self).__init__(data, *args, **kwargs)

      def clean_comment(self):
          cleaned_data = self.cleaned_data
          cleaned_comment = cleaned_data.get('comment',Decimal('0.00'))

      def clean(self):
          cleaned_data = self.cleaned_data
          current_time = timezone.now()
          if current_time > self.auction_event.end_time:
            raise ValidationError('This auction event has expired.')
          return cleaned_data

      def save(self, force_insert=False, force_update=False, commit=False):
          comment = super(CommentForm, self).save(commit=False)
          comment.auction_event = self.auction_event
          comment.commenter = self.commenter 
          comment.save()
          self.auction_event.save()
          return comment
```

and in the end this is my view

```
@login_required
def view_comment_history(request, auction_event_id):
    try:
        auction_event = AuctionEvent.objects.get(pk=auction_event_id)
    except AuctionEvent.DoesNotExist:
        raise Http404

    comments = auction_event.comments.all()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = CommentForm(data=request.POST, auction_event=auction_event, commenter=request.user.user,)
        if form.is_valid():
            comments = form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(request.get_full_path())
    else:
        form = CommentForm()

    return render_to_response('lebay/view_comment_history.html', {
        'auction_event': auction_event,
    'form': form,
        'comments': comments,
    }, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

anyone knows why?

Comment: Are you sure you want to store a decimal value in the comments field ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to return your cleaned comment.

```
  def clean_comment(self):
      cleaned_data = self.cleaned_data
      cleaned_comment = cleaned_data.get('comment',Decimal('0.00'))
      return cleaned_comment
```

Comment: Happy to help. Mark as accepted answer if you're happy with it :)